# File 'root/res/layout/custom_spinner.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, payment-gateway

Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'root/res/layout/custom_spinner.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

In Android studio this type issue created
This is 'custom_spinner.xml' atom payment gateway sdk internal file how to resolve it every one can you tell .... suggestions
It showing on release sign app bundle time

Comment: you need to add more details in your question . and add your code where the problem is appeared.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's showing on sign app bundle create time

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue on my case in bank site payment gateway code version old (deprecated code) issue so that's I will remove all bank payment gateway code and new payment gateway added on my android project that solved my problem .